# SiegelTheta gives misleading message when the dimensions don't match

Tags: bugs, special-functions

**Bug introduced in 6.0 and persisting through 13.2.0**

*`SiegelTheta` is new in 6.0*

---

In order to test the `SiegelTheta` function, I wanted to evaluate it for $\mathbf s=\mathbf 0$ when $\mathbf \Omega=(i/\pi)\mathbf I_n$ for some nonnegative integer $n$. (This ought to factorize to the $n$th power of the $n=1$ case, which is itself a Jacobi theta function.)

Strangely, this works for $n=3$...

```
SiegelTheta[IdentityMatrix[3]*I/π], {0, 0, 0}] // N // Chop
```

> ```
> 5.57006
> ```

but not for other nonnegative integers:

```
SiegelTheta[IdentityMatrix[2]*I/π, {0, 0, 0}]
```

> SiegelTheta::invmat: {{I/π, 0}, {0, I/π}} must be a symmetric matrix with a positive definite imaginary part.

```
SiegelTheta[{{I/π, 0}, {0, I/π}}, {0, 0, 0}]


SiegelTheta[IdentityMatrix[4]*I/π, {0, 0, 0}]
```

> SiegelTheta::invmat: {{I/π, 0, 0, 0}, {0, I/π, 0, 0}, {0, 0, I/π, 0}, {0, 0, 0, I/π}} must be a symmetric matrix with a positive definite imaginary part.

```
SiegelTheta[{{I/π, 0, 0, 0}, {0, I/π, 0, 0}, {0, 0, I/π, 0}, {0, 0, 0, I/π}}, {0, 0, 0}]
```

Given that $\Im \mathbf \Omega=(1/\pi)\mathbf I_n$ evaluates to `True` under the `SymmetricMatrixQ[]` and `PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ[]` commands, I can't see why the error message is popping up. Is there an obvious problem or fix?

Comment: You may want to change the size of the zero vector: for the 2 case, `SiegelTheta[IdentityMatrix[2]*I/\[Pi], {0, 0}] // N // Chop` seems to work.

Comment: @bills That seems to do it, though that makes the error message seem entirely irrelevant.

Comment: Yeah, I'd call it a bug.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for the edit!

Comment: To clarify, one of the requirements of SiegelTheta[] is "If Ω is a p*p matrix, the vectors s and v or v_i must have length p." When you changed to IdentityMatrix[2], your value of s should also switch to {0, 0}. The point remains though that Mathematica is printing the wrong error message.