# SiegelTheta throws errors from calling Range with complex arguments

Tags: bugs, warning-messages, special-functions

**Bug introduced in 8.0 or earlier and persists through 12.1 or later. Fixed in 13.2.0 or earlier**

---

This may or may not be related to the bug reported in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/110500/2305).

I was trying to verify the results [of this challenge over on Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/77051/8478) with the following code:

```
p = {{5., 2., 0., 0.}, {2., 5., 2., -2.}, {0., 2., 5., 0.}, {0., -2., 0., 5.}}
SiegelTheta[I*p/Pi, ConstantArray[0, Length@p]]
```

While I do get the correct result, `SiegelTheta` throws a bunch of of messages via `Range` along the lines of:

> Range::range: "Range specification in Range[-I,I] does not have appropriate bounds."

I've verified this with all of the example matrices in the linked challenge - the larger the matrix, the more of these messages are thrown. The same happens when I generate random positive definite matrices myself with the following code:

```
n = 5;
m = RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, {n, n}]
p = N@IdentityMatrix[n] + m\[Transpose].m;
PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ@p
SiegelTheta[I*p/Pi, ConstantArray[0, n]]
```

I have contacted Wolfram Support and they confirmed that this is a bug. If anyone can reproduce it in earlier Mathematica version, feel free to update the header.

Comment: Using `TracePrint[SiegelTheta[(* stuff *)], Range[__], TraceInternal -> True]` reveals that an internal auxiliary routine is making the bad `Range[]` call, so I would consider this a bug. Comparison with the result from version 5.2 (when `SiegelTheta[]` was a package function as opposed to a built-in) shows consistent results, so the sum is being computed correctly despite the bug. Please file a report when you find the time.

Comment: P.S. if you want to scare the people at code golf with the complexity of the problem, link them to [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-03-01609-0).

Comment: Just got an email from Wolfram Support that this is supposedly fixed in the latest version, but haven't tested it myself yet.

Answer (score 1):

Status update: in `13.2.0` we get

[image: screenshot]

The code is provided below -see also OP:

```
p = {{5., 2., 0., 0.}, {2., 5., 2., -2.}, {0., 2., 5., 0.}, {0., -2., 0., 5.}}
SiegelTheta[I*p/Pi, ConstantArray[0, Length@p]]

n = 5;
m = RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, {n, n}]
p = N@IdentityMatrix[n] + m\[Transpose].m;
PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ@p
SiegelTheta[I*p/Pi, ConstantArray[0, n]]
```

Comment: Code should be included in a copyable form.

Comment: @Artes thanks for the comment. My reasoning is the following: in these type of status update answers where a situation is resolved, the code can be grabbed from the OP. I think it to be more important that with a specific version things run smoothly and thus I provided a screenshot. I will include the code for completeness though, since you brought it up. In previous situations, there were no complaints