# General Theta Functions in Mathematica?

Tags: special-functions, lattices

Given a positive-definite or negative-definite matrix $A$ of size $r \times r$, one can define the corresponding theta function

$$f_{A}(q) = \sum_{v \in \mathbb{Z}^{r}} q^{v^{t}Av} = 1 + a_{1}q + a_{2}q^{2} + \cdots$$

whose coefficients count lattice points of a given square with respect to $A$.  For a particular $A$, in my case $16 \times 16$, I'm trying to use Mathematica to compute $f_{A}(q)$ out to some reasonable order in $q$.  The following seems like the natural first attempt, but it suffers from a few issues.  First, here's my matrix:

`A={{-8, -4, -4, -4, -4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}, {-4, -4, -2, -2, -2, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1}, {-4, -2, -4, -2, -2, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1,0, 0, -1}, {-4, -2, -2, -4, -2, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0}, {-4, -2, -2, -2, -4, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0}, {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {-1, -1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {-1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {-1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2, 0, 0, 0}, {-1, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2, 0, 0}, {-1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2, 0}, {-1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2}}`

And an attempt to approximate the theta function:

`Theta0[k_, q_] :=  Sum[q^(-{n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9, n10, n11, n12, n13, n14, n15, n16}.A.{n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9, n10, n11, n12, n13, n14, n15, n16}), {n1, -k, k}, {n2, -k, k}, {n3, -k, k}, {n4, -k, k}, {n5, -k, k}, {n6, -k, k}, {n7, -k, k}, {n8, -k, k}, {n9, -k, k}, {n10, -k, k}, {n11, -k, k}, {n12, -k, k}, {n13, -k, k}, {n14, -k, k}, {n15, -k, k}, {n16, -k, k}];`

This is summing over the lattice points in the box $[-k,k]^{16}$ for any $k$.  Now, obviously a box does not at all respect the symmetry of the problem, but in principle, for large enough $k$ I will be able to correctly recover some number of coefficients of $q$.

The issue here is that this is extremely inefficient.  Even just $k=2$ wouldn't compute letting my program run.  So I'm wondering if there is a way of streamlining what I'm trying to do here?  Or maybe someone can see an alternative method?  I realize in a rank 16 lattice there are a ton of lattice points to deal with, but I'm hoping that can be overcome somehow!

Comment: Do you remember  that `N` is a built-in function?

Comment: Ahh right, that was silly.  Though I think that couldn't have been the whole issue because my program worked okay, albeit slowly, for $N=1$.

Comment: You should correct you question changing `N` to eg, `nN` or simply `n`.  I guess you should also mention why you are interested in generalized Theta functions as well as  where and how you want to use them.

Comment: `N` here is interpreted by Mathematica as a pattern name, not the built-in function `N`, due to the presence of `N_` on the lhs of the delayed set (`:=`)—so as-is the code is ok, if potentially a bit confusing to the reader! However, if Benighted wanted to use the built-in `N` on the rhs of that delayed set, they'd have some trouble :)

Comment: For clarity, I changed the $N$ to $k$ in my OP.

Comment: In theory, one should be able to use `SiegelTheta[]` for this evaluation. In practice, [`SiegelTheta[]` has a bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111904) that prevents you from actually employing it in this situation.